# SurveyMonkey API Error400 on bad JSON string when JSON string for creating survey poll is valid

Tags: json, api, surveymonkey

I was looking into ways to create surveys programmatically and came across SurveyMonkey APIs. I manually created an empty survey on my account and created a draft app and got an access token from there. And then I **copied & pasted** the example code from the API doc on the section of [creating a survey question](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/?python#surveys-id-pages-id-questions) to try it out.

You can also see the code [here](https://gist.github.com/santina/672f5b57f708af0763adb4b5ead45af2) where the survey ID and the page ID were obtained by using the `/surveys` and `/surveys/{id}/pages` end points.

However, I get this following error.

`{u'error': {u'docs': u'https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#error-codes', u'message': u'The body provided was not a proper JSON string.', u'http_status_code': 400, u'id': u'1001', u'name': u'Bad Request'}}`

I checked that the JSON object is valid and contains all the required parameters as specified in the doc. I also tried some smaller, simpler questions and still no success. If I passed in an empty JSON object, it does complain about the missing required parameters. I was wondering if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you aren't actually sending the body as json properly.

```
url = "https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/%s/pages/%s/questions" % (survey_id, page_id)
r = s.post(url, data=payload)
print r.json()
```

You need to `json.dumps(payload)`

```
import json
url = "https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/%s/pages/%s/questions" % (survey_id, page_id)
r = s.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
print r.json()
```

In newer version of the `requests` library you can use the `json` kwarg for that.

```
url = "https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/%s/pages/%s/questions" % (survey_id, page_id)
r = s.post(url, json=payload)
print r.json()
```

Comment: You're right, I tried both of the approaches and they work! Thank you for saving the day!